# Installing Boost with CMake

Tags: boost, cmake

I am trying to install Boost 1.47.0 using cmake, after many failed trials with the Bjam (it fails to detect my MPI installation). CMake however doesn't find the cmakelist.txt file in the source directory. Any help?
Tarek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Boost didn't choose CMake as a build toolchain, so it won't work. I'd rather try to fix the MPI detection :)

There is this : https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/CMake and its repository http://gitorious.org/boost/cmake
But it seems a bit difficult.

Comment: I got a version for cmake, when I do make install, I get the error message: **Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"                                               
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (FILE):
  file cannot create directory: /usr/local/include/boost-1.47.0.  Maybe need
  administrative privileges.** how can I change the include directory?

Comment: Indeed, when doing the installation, you need adminstrator rights (/usr/ is a system wide rep). Prefix the install command with "sudo" (or login as root). If you don't have admin rights, you need to read documentation about the options (usually it's called "prefix")

Answer (score 1):

That's because there is no CMakeLists.txt. boost is not designed to be built with CMake.